# Symfony2 GenerateURL to a complex route

Tags: symfony, routes

This seems like the dumbest question ever, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I have a page the needs to redirect to a complex route and I can't seem to generate the URL.  Redirecting to a simple route is easy enough:

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('testnumber'));
```

However, I want to route to:  testnumber/1/question/4.  How can I accomplish this incredibly simple task?  The only thing I have found in the documentation and Google allows me to add parameters and not just create a complex route.  For example:

```
generateURL('testnumber', array('testid'=>1, 'question'=>4))
```

makes a URL of /testnumber?testid=1&question=4, which I do not want.

Edit: Yes, I already have the route created in a YML file.  I simply cannot generate the URL to link to it.

```
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(???????????),true));
```

This is my route:

```
@Route("/testnumber/{testid}/question/{question}", name="testnumber")
```

The Symfony documentation only shows how to generate a URL to " testnumber/1", I need to generate "testnumber/1/question/4".

Comment: Do you have a route in your `routing.yml` file with a name of `testnumber` that has `testid` and `question` as parameters? Look [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/routing.html) for an example.

Comment: Can you please show how you define your route?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For

```
generateURL('testnumber', array('testid'=>1, 'question'=>4))
```

to work as you want, your route must look like (example using annotations)

```
@Route("/testnumber/{testid}/question/{question}", name="testnumber")
```

If you don't define "testid" & "question" parameters in your route, they'll be added to the query string (appended at the end of the URL as GET paramaters)

```
generated_route?test_id=X&question=X
```

Find [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/routing.html) more relevent examples.

Comment: My route works fine.  I am trying to figure out how to generate the URL to redirect to that route.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you please update your question with your route definition?

Comment: The route is exactly as you have entered.  I just want to know how to generate that with the generateurl method.

    @Route("/testnumber/{testid}/question/{question}", name="testnumber")

Comment: This works fine > generateURL('testnumber', array('testid'=>1, 'question'=>4))
I just tested it.

Comment: You just typed in the exact thing that I already typed said I did not want.

"generateURL('testnumber', array('testid'=>1, 'question'=>4))" creates a URL of "/testnumber?testid=1&question=4".  

I want to generate the URL "testnumber/1/question/4".

Comment: ->generateURL('testnumber', array('testid'=>1, 'question'=>4))
with the following route definition:
@Route("/testnumber/{testid}/question/{question}",name="testnumber")
Creates (I just tested it) the following url
testnumber/1/question/4 
So, it's ok for the route and the used method :) I've no other idea on what's turning wrong on your route generation.

Comment: I think we have a language problem here.  Can you please complete this line of code? 

'return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(??????????));'  

The route '@Route("/testnumber/{testid}/question/{question}",name="testnumber")' already exists, I just can't seem to link to it.  The Symfony documentation only shows how to link to '/testnumber/{testid}'